# XPath statement not parsing as expected

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Below is the HTML from which I'm trying to select **2016.**

```
<span id="titleYear">
  "("
  <a href="/year/2016/?ref_=tt_ov_inf">2016</a>
  ")"
</span>
```

And here is the XPath statement: `//span[@id='titleYear']/a/text()`

Unfortunately that statement selects `<a href="/year/2016/?ref_=tt_ov_inf">2016</a>` for some reason.

`//span[@id='titleYear']/a/text()` returns the same result as `//span[@id='titleYear']/a` and `//span[@id='titleYear']/a[text()]`.

**Why does `text()` have zero effect in this context?**

**Is it because `2016` isn't considiered a text node?**

Notably, I'm using Anaconda with Python 3.6.5 and Scrapy 1.5.0.

*Python Script*

```
import scrapy

class IMDBcrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imdb'
    def start_requests(self):
        pages = []
        count = 1
        limit = 10
        while (count <= limit):
            str_number = '%07d' % count
            pages.append('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt' + str_number)
            count += 1
        for url in pages:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'nom': response.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"]/h1/text()').extract_first(),
            'ano': response.xpath('//span[@id="titleYear"]/a/text()').extract_first(),
        }
```

*Output*

```
[
  {
    "nom": "Chinese Opium Den\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1894\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1894<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Pauvre Pierrot\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1892\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1892<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Carmencita\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1894\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1894<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Un bon bock\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1892\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1892<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Blacksmith Scene\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1893\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1893<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Corbett and Courtney Before the Kinetograph\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1894\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1894<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Employees Leaving the Lumi\u00e8re Factory\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1895\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1895<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Miss Jerry\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1894\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1894<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Le clown et ses chiens\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1892\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1892<\/a>"
  },
  {
    "nom": "Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze\u00a0",
    "ano": "<a href=\"\/year\/1894\/?ref_=tt_ov_inf\">1894<\/a>"
  }
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what tool(s) are you testing with? That XPath expression in fact should select the text node `2016`, not instead that `a` element node.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I'm using scrapy in Python. I'll upload the script and the output so you can get a better idea of what's going on

Comment: It works fine for me with Python 3.6.3 and Scrapy 1.5.0. Are you sure you are using this `response.xpath('//span[@id="titleYear"]/a/text()').extract_first()` expression and you didn't forget to include the `extract_first()`?

Comment: @VMRuiz 100%. Perhaps then it is an issue with Anaconda or even the Visual Studio Code editor?!?! Notably, I was also experiencing the very same issue in the Chrome browser when trying to select `2016` with the XPath statement :/

Comment: @VMRuiz super strange. now all of a sudden it's working as expected even though i haven't touched the code... maybe cuz the content is generated by javascript?! i'm at a loss right now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is using `Scrapy`, however using `lxml` directly with the help of requests, a simpler `xpath` using `findtext` works fine:

```
import requests

from lxml import html

pages = []

for count in range(1, 10):
    str_num = '%07d' % count
    res = html.fromstring(requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt' + str_num).text)
    pages.append({'nom': res.findtext('.//div[@class="title_wrapper"]/h1'), 'ano': res.findtext('.//span[@id="titleYear"]/a')})
```

Results in:

```
In [40]: pages
Out[40]:
[{'ano': '1894', 'nom': 'Carmencita\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1892', 'nom': 'Le clown et ses chiens\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1892', 'nom': 'Pauvre Pierrot\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1892', 'nom': 'Un bon bock\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1893', 'nom': 'Blacksmith Scene\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1894', 'nom': 'Chinese Opium Den\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1894', 'nom': 'Corbett and Courtney Before the Kinetograph\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1894', 'nom': 'Edison Kinetoscopic Record of a Sneeze\xa0'},
 {'ano': '1894', 'nom': 'Miss Jerry\xa0'}]
```

Comment: although i've messed around with Python in the past, i'm a complete n00b when it comes to scrapy and even more so XPath. with that being said, is `lxml` another crawler framework or something?

Comment: @Anthony `lxml` is pretty much the go to XML/HTML parsing library for python. And from reading the Spider docs, this is what is used under the hood. However I just tried your code and I don't have the same problem, so it maybe something to do with a version of the library you are using (either lxml or Spider)

Comment: i'm surprised i had never even heard of `lxml` until now since i had spent a good little while searching for the "best" python frameworks. everybody suggets scrapy and sometimes beautifulsoup. really?! can you open a chat and show me the output u got?! i'm using anaconda with python 3.6.5 and scrapy version 1.5.0